# Spring: Configuring Bean with a two argument setter

Tags: java, spring, configuration, javabeans

I would like to configure a HttpParams using spring setter injection but HttpParams has a two argument setter ( setParameter(String name, Object object) ).  Is anyone aware of a way to configure this in spring?

The closest I can think of is like you would do a List, Set, or Property configuration:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-collections-list-set-map-and-properties-example/

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Strictly speaking: A setter with two parameters is not a setter.
It violates the JavaBeans convention, on which Spring builds. There is no simple way to solve that.

---

As an alternative, here's a Helper class you can use to configure your HttpParams object with Spring:

```
public class HttpParamSetter{

    private HttpParams httpParams;

    public void setHttpParams(HttpParams httpParams){
        this.httpParams = httpParams;
    }

    private Map<String, Object> parameters;

    public void setParameters(Map<String, Object> parameters){
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void applyParameters(){
        for(Entry<String, Object> entry:parameters.entrySet()){
            httpParams.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

    }

}
```

Wire it like this:

```
<bean class="com.yourcompany.HttpParamSetter">
    <property name="httpParams" ref="httpParams" />
    <property name="parameters">
        <map>
            <entry key="foo" value="bar" />
            <entry key="baz" value="phleem" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks I thought there wasn't a way to do it purely using spring what we ended up doing is implementing a Spring FactoryBean that can supply the necessary connection factory then the config looks like:  <bean class ="org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient"><constructor-arg index="o" ref="httpParamFactory"/></bean>  with httpParamFactory being an instance of our FactoryBean.

Comment: @craftsmanadam I was initially going to suggest that, but I didn't know if you created the Params object yourself, so I went for a solution that should always work (but yours is probably more spring-like)

Answer (score 3):

I believe HttpConnectionParamBean and HttpProtocolParamBean were created for precisely this purpose. [Documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/params/HttpAbstractParamBean.html) [Example](http://code.google.com/p/groovy-http/source/browse/trunk/src/test/resources/spring-context.xml?r=83)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Apache HttpClient? If so, the HttpClientParams implementation of HttpParams has real getters and setters that you can use.

Otherwise, I'd suggest writing a simple HttpParamsFactory that you could pass a map that contains the parameters you need and construct an appropriate instance of HttpParams.