# Is possible to inject method with arguments in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, methods, arguments, inject

From docs:

> In the client class containing the method to be injected (the CommandManager in this case), the method that is to be 'injected' must have a signature of the following form:

```
<public|protected> [abstract] <return-type> theMethodName(no-arguments);
```

Does exists way to workaround this limitation?

Comment: What would you want Spring to do with the arguments of the method?

Comment: Try [this](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?32785-Lookup-method-injection-with-parameters). It's old, but contains useful pointers.

Comment: Check selected answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349362/spring-bean-initialization-with-multiple-arg-method
It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can.  Here is an example from  the spring docs, http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html

```
 @Autowired
 public void prepare(MovieCatalog movieCatalog,
                   CustomerPreferenceDao customerPreferenceDao) {
   this.movieCatalog = movieCatalog;
   this.customerPreferenceDao = customerPreferenceDao;
 }
```

Comment: Isn't OP asking about lookup methods? It's literally the method that is getting injected via proxying, not a method being injected its arguments.

Comment: mmm, the question was a little hard to understand.  I thought I had the meaning of it...but reading your comment and re-reading the question, it sounds like you could be correct.

Comment: How do you call such a method? WIth 0 arguments and then some magic in an overloaded method will get the beans/arguments from the context?