# What is the best way to call a method(with parameters) right after a class is instantiated using a bean?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have read up on @PostConstruct and init-method but they don't allow args to be passed from the bean.

Something along the line of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349362/spring-bean-initialization-with-multiple-arg-method). But the args-to-be-passed are from the class that instantiates the bean.

To simplify: **Invoker** is the class that instantiates **Invoked** class and calls **Invoked.Method(args)** where the args are from **Invoker.Args**.

The question is can I do all this in Beans? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am not sure I can fully understand your problem. Any particular reason why you can not pass the arguments in the constructor of the Invoked, and just call the method after? A short example or some more details of your workflow might help understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO something like the code below should work, assuming that args created as part of Invoker class or autowired into it:

```
@Component
class Invoker {
   private String[] args = new String[]("1","2","3")

   @Autowired
   private Invoked invoked;

   @PostConstruct
   private void init() {
      invoked.method(args);
   } 

}
```