# JsonParseException : Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)

Tags: java, json, character-encoding, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to use `org.apache.httpcomponents` to consume a Rest API, which will post JSON format data to API.

I get this exception:

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal
>   unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using
>   backslash to be included in string.

The reason is because `ctrl-char` is included in the JSON string.

Is there any way to replace this or some other solution?

Comment: Are you creating the JSON yourself? Basically, it sounds like you've got broken data... so either fix it if you can, or complain to whoever's producing it.

Comment: As discussed in [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17487154/1720082), does your JSON validate correctly via [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)?

Comment: Intellij idea validates it as soon as you open the .json file. Try it!

Comment: I had code 9 issue - it was because of [TAB] character

Comment: You forgot the double quote in parameter: "param: 123, instead of "param": 123

Answer (score 135):

This can happen if you have a newline (or other control character) in a JSON string literal.

```
{"foo": "bar
baz"}
```

If you are the one producing the data, replace actual newlines with escaped ones `"\\n"` when creating your string literals.

```
{"foo": "bar\nbaz"}
```

Comment: unfortunately, the reason why I have new lines is because the string is big and I would like it to be readable. Actual new lines make the string helps toward this goal

Comment: @juanchito Adding newlines to literals change what the literals _are_.  You cannot add them there solely for readability, because it changes their _meaning_.  Put the newlines between tokens instead of inside them.  And regardless, format things for the server when you are submitting to it; human readability before or after is not relevant and should be handled separately.

Comment: You can trim newlines before sending the payload, getting both readability and correct JSON.

Answer (score 90):

Using

```java
mapper.configure(
    JsonReadFeature.ALLOW_UNESCAPED_CONTROL_CHARS.mappedFeature(), 
    true
);
```

See [javadoc](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/json/JsonReadFeature.html#ALLOW_UNESCAPED_CONTROL_CHARS):

```
/**
 * Feature that determines whether parser will allow
 * JSON Strings to contain unescaped control characters
 * (ASCII characters with value less than 32, including
 * tab and line feed characters) or not.
 * If feature is set false, an exception is thrown if such a
 * character is encountered.
 *<p>
 * Since JSON specification requires quoting for all control characters,
 * this is a non-standard feature, and as such disabled by default.
 */
```

Old option `JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS` was deprecated since 2.10.

Please see also [github thread](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/586).

Comment: how to implement this in xml ? I have `<mvc:annotation-driven>
<mvc:message-converters>
<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
<property name="objectMapper">
<bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper">
<property name="serializationInclusion" value="NON_NULL"/>
</bean>
</property>
<property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
</bean>
</mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>`  . I am using Jackson 2.7. and Spring4.3.2

Comment: Why don't you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349362/spring-bean-initialization-with-multiple-arg-method
Or overriding that bean: MappingJackso‌​n2HttpMessageConvert‌​er

Comment: @hoang where to delare this in java as I am trying to capture this illegal data, I have asked the question which is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676720/post-illegal-unquoted-character-in-json-data-as-a-request?noredirect=1#comment86384077_49676720, can you please help me out.

Comment: thanks really useful, the import i used was:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.Feature;`

Comment: what is `mapper`. please, provide context on how it is used

Comment: this is ObjectMapper of Jackson, please see: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

Answer (score 1):

On Salesforce platform this error is caused by `/`, the solution is to escape these as `//`.

Comment: For me - on Salesforce platform - it was "\" to "\\" that was actually needed. At least in my case it occured because of new line characters in my JSON. `\n` had to be changed to `\\n`. This is due to the fact that JSON requires control characters to be escaped. See this excellent comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json#comment23184783_42073).

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you are sending JSON data to server.
Maybe in your string you are trying to add new line character by using /n.

If you add / before /n, it should work, you need to escape new line character.

```
"Hello there //n start coding"
```

The result should be as following

```
Hello there
start coding
```

Answer (score -1):

JsonParseException : Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)

Solution:
Exists in your text a chr TAB, before put text in the json, use replace chr TAB to \t

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Tab is code 9, not code 10.  Please see the existing answers.