# Post Illegal unquoted character in Json data as a Request

Tags: java, json, exception

I am trying to get JSON data from user (any format). I want to take that data and validate it and then store it in database.
I have written code for getting the data and storing it, which is working very fine, problem come when I try to send some Illegal data from user which is giving me error as  `Illegal unquoted character` How do I get illegal data from user and handle it with exception clause.
My class for getting data is

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class EventData extends BasicDBObject{
    /**
     * Social information of user
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Object data;

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

I have controller which will get the data and call the appropriate service to handle it. I think we need to add some code here in pojo class which will allow illegal JSON data.

I am getting exception as

```
21:17:14,606 ERROR ExceptionHandler:38 - Could not read document: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1a67dc76; line: 35, column: 38]
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1a67dc76; line: 35, column: 19] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[2]->com.microinvest.documents.UserActionEvent["eventData"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1a67dc76; line: 35, column: 38]
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1a67dc76; line: 35, column: 19] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[2]->com.microinvest.documents.UserActionEvent["eventData"])
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1a67dc76; line: 35, column: 38]
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1a67dc76; line: 35, column: 19] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[2]->com.microinvest.documents.UserActionEvent["eventData"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1a67dc76; line: 35, column: 38]
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1a67dc76; line: 35, column: 19] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[2]->com.microinvest.documents.UserActionEvent["eventData"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:228)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at com.microinvest.config.CORSFilter.doFilterInternal(CORSFilter.java:23)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I went through some ques and link and I found that I have to use some thing like

```
mapper.configure(Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS, true);
```

from link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537153/jsonparseexception-illegal-unquoted-character-ctrl-char-code-10)

but I am not sure how to use It. any link or code will be very helpful.

Comment: One possible way is to read the data yourself as bytes from the InputStream, and then try to sanitize them before you convert the JSON. However, when the input format is specified to be JSON it is probably best to reject input that is not valid JSON.

Comment: @Henry What if I have an array of json data coming from post request and I want to iterate over that data and use validate and check which one is correct and store it, and those which are wrong reject it.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But the problem is that strictly speaking you don't have an "array of JSON data" if it is not syntactically correct. So you cannot use JSON tools to operate on it.

Comment: according to requirement I have an "array of json data". I posted this question to know How can I receive incorrect JSON data. let suppose I want to store which user sent incorrect data and who has sent correct data.

Answer (score 2):

According to the post from which I found the solution, you don't need to do much but add:

```
spring.jackson.parser.allow-unquoted-control-chars=true
```

To your configuration file, restart your spring-boot app, and that's all.

[Find the post here for more information](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/586)

Answer (score 1):

[@JsonDeserialize](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html) should help you with this you can write your custom deserializer class which can do validation on data like so:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class DataHandler extends StdDeserializer<Object> {
    protected DataHandler(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    public Object deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String str = jsonParser.getText();
        String validatedStr = validateStr(str);
        return str;
    }

    private String validateStr(String str) {
        // write validation code here. Handle illegal quoted characters, add try/catch, etc
        return str;
    }
}
```

Once you have that you can simply annotate `private Object data;` with your `DataHandler` like so:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class EventData extends BasicDBObject{
    /**
     * Social information of user
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = DataHandler.class)
    private Object data;

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Notice the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation on the `data` above. Good article to read on this with a working example is [here](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2018/02/how-to-parse-json-with-date-field-in-java-jackson-example.html)

Comment: this also does not work for me as the output remains the same.