# Linebreaks in a JIRA HTTP call

Tags: api, jira

My automation setup makes a HTTP call to JIRA that includes a variable pulled from the test results before that. The variable sometimes has line breaks which error out the HTTP call because of syntax issues.

```
{
"fields": {
   "project":
   {
      "key": "Blah"
   },
   "assignee": {
      "name": "Joe"
    },
   "summary": "Summary",
   "description": "${variable}",
   "issuetype": {
      "name": "Defect"
   }
}
```

In the HTTP call, ${variable} is replaced with this:

```
{
"fields": {
   "project":
   {
      "key": "Blah"
   },
   "assignee": {
      "name": "Joe"
    },
   "summary": "Summary",
   "description": "Test failed: text expected to equal /

****** received  : 
[[[{"id":700,"status":"FAIL","color":"#D45D52","testKey":"TEST-329","testExecKey":"TEST-355","assig...]]]

****** comparison: [[[asdasdasdasd                                                                                           
]]]

/",

   "issuetype": {
      "name": "Defect"
   }
}
```

As a response I get this:

```
{"errorMessages":["Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@39cf8e10; line: 14, column: 62]"]}
```

How can I implement the variable so that the format does not break?

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537153/jsonparseexception-illegal-unquoted-character-ctrl-char-code-10) suggests that you should replace the newline characters with escaped newline characters (i.e. before sending your variable, iterate through it and replace all `\n` with `\\n`)