# Uploading multipart form-data linux file using Rest template : I/O error on POST request for Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 13))

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, multipartform-data, resttemplate

I'm having issues uploading a file via resttemplate client on linux

Here's what I have currently

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> form = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    form.add("image", new FileSystemResource(imageFile));
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(form, headers);
    UploadResponse response = restTemplate.postForEntity(uploadUrl,httpEntity, UploadResponse.class).getBody();
```

Code works fine on windows but returns this error on linux:

```
 I/O error on POST request for "https://baseurl/api/v1/upload": Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 13)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 47]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 13)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value
```

Anyone has an idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Try to just print new FileSystemResource(imageFile) and see if it picks up the image file correctly on linux or not.

Comment: @SusanMustafa Yes it picks up the image correctly on linux

Comment: Curious, could you try to setContentType("multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8"); instead.  Lets see how it reacts.

Comment: Okay I'll try this

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this seems to be to update your ObjectMapper to ignore CTRL characters, which Linux might be inferring

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

private void patchRestTemplate() {

    objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);

    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().forEach(httpMessageConverter -> {

        if (httpMessageConverter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {

            ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) httpMessageConverter).setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        }
    });
}
```

Reference: [JsonParseException : Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537153/jsonparseexception-illegal-unquoted-character-ctrl-char-code-10)

Comment: Didn't work for me, got the same error

Comment: Are you actually patching the restTemplate before doing restTemplate.postForEntity??

Comment: I've just figured out the issue. Thanks very much. Your solution helped put me on the right path. an existing internal restTemplate client interceptor logger library I was using did not cater for logging "multipart/form-data" requests.